# Drop leading zeroes from strings in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

How do I drop the first `0`s out of the the following text using the same formula?

`0700.hk` --> `700.hk`

`0027.hk` --> `27.hk`

`0001.hk` --> `1.hk`

some will not have a zero

`1929.hk` --> `1929.hk`

Comment: @pnuts because people who are familiar with and using excel can also provide a solution. And people who use excel can also benefit from this answer.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to post these Q's on Web Applications the next time. As you can see, Excel vs. Google Spreadsheets ins't exactly the same: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/are-excel-formulas-and-google-spreadsheet-formulas-the-same/44719#44719 and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44715/excel-to-google-spreadsheet-problem/44722#44722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Google spreadsheets there is a function called `REGEXREPLACE`. So you can `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^0+","")` to remove the leading zeros.

Comment: That is sick. Great answer!

Comment: The answer is great and worked like a charm for me too. Could you add an explanation of exactly what the ^ and + do? I understand it does the following: search in A1, find 0 (and something magic about them (the `^` and `+`)), replace them with empty space (the `""`).

Comment: Canned Man- the ^ means at the start of the string and the + means one or more occurrences… so basically it just says to replace one or more occurrences of 0 at the start of the string with nothing

Answer (score 3):

This works in Excel for the four examples you provide:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".hk",A1)-1))&".hk"
```

It presumably works in Google Spreadsheet as well, though I haven't tested it there.

You can shorten it a little bit, assuming it's always a sequence of digits followed by `.hk`:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)&".hk"
```

In fact, you can shorten it even more if you know it's always a sequence of *four* digits followed by `.hk` (as noted by @Cole Lange in a comment to this answer):

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,4))&".hk"
```

Comment: Why so? And what do you mean, a single function?

Comment: Ah... Sure, but does such a single function exist? That removes leading zeroes from strings? I'm all ears!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. Thanks for the answer. I was trying `left` `mid` `right` functions without success. The `search` function was what I needed. Thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: The only way I could see shortening this would be if the cells were ONLY 4 numbers each, in which case you could remove the `SEARCH()` function and replace it with `4`.

Comment: @pnuts: Well well, I'm glad to see a superior answer to mine! Vote to close it as off-topic? ;-)